# Method that returns a new array where each element is the square or the original element

Tags: c#

I'm trying to get an array of N numbers and then print them. I receive this error. I looked at some examples but I don't know what is **wrong**:

```
{
        int[] myArray = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };

        //for (int i = 0; i < myArray.Length; i++)
        //{
        //    Console.WriteLine(Math.Pow(myArray[i],2));
        //}
    }

    private static int squareArray(int[] array)
    {
        int[] result = new int[array.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            result[i] = Math.Pow(array[i], 2);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: squareArray should return an `int[]` instead of `int`.

Comment: Yeah, i try that but Systax error, value expected or something like this i receive.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please include the error you mention, what the program should do, and what the program is doing wrong. Otherwise, it's tough for us to help you.

Comment: `Math.Pow()` returns a double, so you can't put that into an int array without casting the return value back to an int. But you don't need to use `Math.Pow()` to square it, just do this: `result[i] = array[i] * array[i];` But watch out for overflow - you can't square more than Sqrt(int.MaxValue)

Comment: I m trying, and when i say trying, i really trying to write a method to return square of array elements. But with not luck :) something is missing here but cant see what/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
private static int[] squareArray(int[] array)
{
    int[] result = new int[array.Length];
    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
    {
        result[i] = (int)Math.Pow(array[i], 2);
    }
    return result;
}
```

or you can do it simpler like this:

```
var squaredArray = array.Select(x=>x*x).ToArray();
```

Comment: He didn't change the return value from his `int` to your corrected `int[]` I bet.

Comment: Well, he can copy/paste my code. I've provided 2 examples.